# How to show all the data that has been imported to the MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using Nodejs and MongoDB. First I have imported the excel sheet named `sample.csv` to the MongoDB. Now I want to show all the data that  has been imported into the MongoDB. My question is in this case how shall I create the instance.

The code that I am using in node.js is given below:

```
router.route('/user/:_id/sample')
.get(function(req, res)
       .find(function(err, sample) {
               if (err) {
                       res.send(err);
               }
               res.json(sample);
       });
 });
```

Comment: Can you show us what you tried so far in terms of MongoDB and where your actual problems are?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg: I have imported the excel sheet in the MongoDB now, I want to list all the data that I have imported into the DB. I have created a route /user/:_id/sample. Now I want to show all the data in this link.

Comment: Neal: you just dropped in some rather meaningless code only loosely related to your question and say what you want. I, for my part, want free beer and world peace. ;) Just by paraphrasing what you have already written, you don't help us (me, at least) to help you. Stackoverflow is there to help you with existing code, not to provide you with snippets you want.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg: Thanks. Please can you mention what exactly you want. Then it would be very helpful for me to provide.

Comment: Your code is not a valid JavaScript.

Comment: The code where you try to set up the database connection would be a good start. The description of your actual problems doing the connection would be useful, of course. Maybe a link to the docs you are using.